# Proving the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite for any dimension

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I understand how the Lebesgue measure on the real line is $\sigma$-finite, but I don't understand how to prove that the lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite for any dimension. Here I'm using the definition of $\sigma$-finite as follows;

A measure $\mu$ on a measurable space ($X$,$\Sigma$) is $\sigma$-finite if there exists a sequence of measurable sets $E_1$,$E_2$,... $\in$ $\Sigma$ such that $X$ = $\cup^{\infty}_{k=1}$$E_k$ and $\mu (E_k)$ < $\infty$ for every $k \geq 1$.

Thank you to anyone who could explain this to me!

Comment: Do you want to prove it's $\sigma-$finite?  It must be $\sigma$-additive to be a measure.

Comment: Yes, sorry I do. Edited now! @saulspatz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $n$, 
\begin{align*}
{\bf{R}}^{n}=\bigcup_{(N_{1},...,N_{n})\in{\bf{Z}}^{n}}\left[N_{1},N_{1}+1\right)\times\cdots\times\left[N_{n},N_{n}+1\right)
\end{align*}
and $|\left[N_{1},N_{1}+1\right)\times\cdots\times\left[N_{n},N_{n}+1\right)|=1<\infty$ for each $(N_{1},...,N_{n})\in{\bf{Z}}^{n}$.

Comment: Thank you, so where did you get the $N+1$ from and how did you figure out that the measure is 1?

Comment: About the measure, simply because for boxes, one splits: $|[N_{1},N_{1}+1)\times\cdots\times[N_{n},N_{n}+1)|=|[N_{1},N_{1}+1)|\times\cdots\times|[N_{n},N_{n}+1)|=1\times\cdots\times 1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just the countable union of $n$-dimensional cubes centered at the origin, each of which has finite measure (since each is a bounded cube). Explicitly, 
$$
\mathbb{R}^n = \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty [-i,  i]^n.
$$
Then the measure of each $E_i = [-i, i]^n$ is finite, and your whole space is the countable union of the $E_i$.